# When using UrlFetchApp.oAuthConfig how can I get a user's approval without asking them to run the script from the script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can get user authorization for DocsList/SitesApp/etc using a menu item or button, but approval for an oAuthConfig based UrlFetch action is different.  It seems you can only approve those from within the script editor.

Are there any other ways I can get approval for a specific oAuth scope by a user?  My use case is against the mail migration API of which three-legged oAuth is acceptable from any user in a Google Apps for Business domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression. oAuth authorization popup used to work from the menu just fine, I am sure of it. It was a weird blank popup with only an "Authorize" button, weird, but did the job.

Apparently I haven't been using this for a long time, since [issue 677](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) (regarding this) was opened July 2011 :P

Anyway, you should "star" it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

Comment: Right, and that works just fine when you use SitesApp, DocsList, DocumentApp, or any number of Apps Script services that are implemented.  It doesn't work when you use the OAuthConfig configuration options of UrlFetchApp.  Running a function that needs an OAuth approval from a button or menu item in the Spreadsheet fails with no error message.

Comment: You're right, I have updated my answer after new tests. My original answer was based on old behavior.